# Item spacing in UICollectionView iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating an application in which i want to use UICollectionView. I have used this, but i am seeing the black space between to items and two items are moved to left and right side of screen.

```
internal func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 20
    }

    internal func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("productCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductCell
        return cell
    }

     internal func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: Please add screenshot of the app , also attach a screenshot of attribute inspector of your collection view if you have added it from nib.

Comment: Really need a screenshot of what you have at the moment and a better description of what you are trying to achieve.